# "has" versus "have" after the preposition "of"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-tense

In the sentences

> A copy of your documents has been emailed to you@gmail.com.
>
> A copy of your documents have been emailed to you@gmail.com.

I believe the subject is "copy", and since "has" refers to the third person singular ("it" being "copy") I believe the first sentence to be correct. Does the preposition change the focus of the subject to "documents" or does it remain singular ("copy")? I don't think the subject has become "documents" at any point in the sentence.

Even if there were multiple items after the "of", such as

> A copy of your documents and files (has/have) been emailed to you@gmail.com.

would the subject still be "copy" or is it now the items?

Comment: That’s right, * has* agrees numerically with *copy* in your example.

Comment: Subjects can't change in the middle of a sentence.